# Building a model for research question

Tags: ancova, lm

The question of interest is whether the relationship between A and B is the same for each level of Type. The data is in long format and looks somewhat like this...
[image: data]

A is a numerical variable and so is B. Type is a factor with 4 levels...

I'm trying to answer the question in R and so far I've come up with this model

lm(A ~ B + Type + B:Type, data = sample)

Running anova on this, I can say that there is an interaction term between B & Type due to the low p-value on the interaction term, which would mean that since the effect of B depends on Type, the relationship of A~B is dependent on Type. But I feel that there is a better way to build a model for this question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to CV. You would be much more likely to get a response if you carefully stipulate your research question(s) rather than the oblique manner you've used here.

Comment: If possible, can you also explain the reason for this feeling? What led you to think so? It may give clues as to what needs to be explained.

Answer (score 1):

The model you have fitted is an appropriate one* for investigating whether the lines differ.

A non-zero interaction says whether the slopes are different. (The coefficient for Type itself relates to a difference in intercept.)

*(as long as the assumptions under which your p-value was calculated were reasonably close to true)

However, it doesn't show you much about how big the effect is -- a statistically significant effect may be very small. As such, I'd seek to visualize the effect by plotting both the data and the fitted pair of regression lines (each colored by "Type").